# VSTS Cordova Android Build Job stuck

Tags: android, cordova, azure-devops, visual-studio-cordova

Using the Hosted VS2017 machines for an ionic / cordova build job and no matter what I seem to change it just gets stuck:

```
Queueing build for platform android w/options: --release,--device,--gradleArg=--no-daemon
Processing res/native for android
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
Welcome to Gradle 4.8!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Dependency locking
 - Maven Publish and Ivy Publish plugins improved and marked stable
 - Incremental annotation processing enhancements
 - APIs to configure tasks at creation time
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :wrapper
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 34s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I read in the VSTS documentation that the gradle daemon will get stuck so your supposed to add a hook into the after_compile folder

```
IF EXIST platforms\android platforms\android\gradlew --stop
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. I've tried removing the code signing in my build.json but that also doesn't seem to help, I've even tried bootstrapping the entire process through npm

`npm run cordova -- build android --release --device --gradleArg=--no-daemon`

same issue. I've tried Cordova 6.5.0, 7.1.0 and 8.0.0 in my taco.json, same issue. I really feel like it's the gradle daemon getting stuck but the hooks are being ignored, or they were changed and I just can't find what or where they should go now.

Build definition:

```
{
  "badgeEnabled": null,
  "buildNumberFormat": null,
  "comment": null,
  "createdDate": "2018-07-18T15:31:11.333000+00:00",
  "demands": null,
  "description": null,
  "draftOf": null,
  "dropLocation": null,
  "id": ,
  "jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
  "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
  "jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
  "latestBuild": null,
  "latestCompletedBuild": null,
  "metrics": null,
  "name": "Mobile Builds",
  "path": "\\project",
  "process": {
    "phases": [
      {
        "condition": "succeeded()",
        "jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
        "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
        "name": "Android",
        "refName": "Phase_1",
        "steps": [
          {
            "alwaysRun": false,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "continueOnError": false,
            "displayName": "install",
            "enabled": true,
            "environment": {},
            "inputs": {
              "command": "install",
              "customCommand": "",
              "customEndpoint": "",
              "customFeed": "",
              "customRegistry": "useNpmrc",
              "publishEndpoint": "",
              "publishFeed": "",
              "publishRegistry": "useExternalRegistry",
              "verbose": "false",
              "workingDir": "WorkDir"
            },
            "task": {
              "definitionType": "task",
              "id": "fe47e961-9fa8-4106-8639-368c022d43ad",
              "versionSpec": "1.*"
            },
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0
          },
          {
            "alwaysRun": false,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "continueOnError": false,
            "displayName": "gulp sass",
            "enabled": true,
            "environment": {},
            "inputs": {
              "command": "custom",
              "customCommand": "run gulp -- sass",
              "customEndpoint": "",
              "customFeed": "",
              "customRegistry": "useNpmrc",
              "publishEndpoint": "",
              "publishFeed": "",
              "publishRegistry": "useExternalRegistry",
              "verbose": "false",
              "workingDir": "WorkDir"
            },
            "task": {
              "definitionType": "task",
              "id": "fe47e961-9fa8-4106-8639-368c022d43ad",
              "versionSpec": "1.*"
            },
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0
          },
          {
            "alwaysRun": false,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "continueOnError": false,
            "displayName": "Cordova Build android",
            "enabled": true,
            "environment": {},
            "inputs": {
              "antBuild": "false",
              "archs": "",
              "configuration": "release",
              "cordovaArgs": "",
              "cordovaVersion": "",
              "cwd": "WorkDir",
              "defaultKeychainPassword": "",
              "iosSignMethod": "file",
              "iosSigningIdentity": "",
              "keyPass": "",
              "keystoreAlias": "",
              "keystoreFile": "",
              "keystorePass": "",
              "outputPattern": "bin",
              "p12": "",
              "p12pwd": "",
              "platform": "android",
              "provProfile": "",
              "provProfileUuid": "",
              "removeProfile": "false",
              "targetEmulator": "false",
              "unlockDefaultKeychain": "false",
              "windowsAppx": "",
              "windowsOnly": "false",
              "windowsPhoneOnly": "false",
              "xcodeDeveloperDir": ""
            },
            "task": {
              "definitionType": "task",
              "id": "70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7",
              "versionSpec": "1.*"
            },
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0
          },
          {
            "alwaysRun": false,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "continueOnError": false,
            "displayName": "Copy Release Notes to Android Build Folder",
            "enabled": true,
            "environment": {},
            "inputs": {
              "CleanTargetFolder": "false",
              "Contents": "release-notes.txt",
              "OverWrite": "false",
              "SourceFolder": "WorkDir",
              "TargetFolder": "bin/Android/Release",
              "flattenFolders": "false"
            },
            "task": {
              "definitionType": "task",
              "id": "5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c",
              "versionSpec": "2.*"
            },
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0
          },
          {
            "alwaysRun": false,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "continueOnError": false,
            "displayName": "Publish Artifact: Android",
            "enabled": true,
            "environment": {},
            "inputs": {
              "ArtifactName": "Android",
              "ArtifactType": "Container",
              "Parallel": "false",
              "ParallelCount": "8",
              "PathtoPublish": "WorkDir/bin/Android/Release",
              "TargetPath": ""
            },
            "task": {
              "definitionType": "task",
              "id": "2ff763a7-ce83-4e1f-bc89-0ae63477cebe",
              "versionSpec": "1.*"
            },
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0
          }
        ],
        "target": {
          "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": false,
          "executionOptions": {
            "type": 0
          },
          "type": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": 1
  },
  "processParameters": {
    "additionalProperties": {},
    "dataSourceBindings": null,
    "inputs": null,
    "sourceDefinitions": null
  },
  "properties": {},
  "quality": "definition",
  "queue": {
    "additionalProperties": {},
    "id": 288,
    "name": "Hosted VS2017",
    "pool": {
      "additionalProperties": {},
      "id": 10,
      "isHosted": true,
      "name": "Hosted VS2017"
    },
    "url": "https://account.visualstudio.com/_apis/build/Queues/288"
  },
  "queueStatus": "enabled",
  "repository": {
    "additionalProperties": {},
    "checkoutSubmodules": false,
    "clean": "false",
    "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/master",
    "id": "ce667db8-941e-47a6-b191-3cb5cf478f69",
    "name": "repo",
    "properties": {
      "checkoutNestedSubmodules": "false",
      "cleanOptions": "0",
      "fetchDepth": "0",
      "gitLfsSupport": "false",
      "labelSources": "0",
      "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)",
      "reportBuildStatus": "true",
      "skipSyncSource": "false"
    },
    "rootFolder": null,
    "type": "TfsGit",
    "url": "https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo"
  },
  "revision": 15,
  "tags": [],
  "triggers": null,
  "type": "build",
  "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Definition/160",
  "url": "https://account.visualstudio.com/guid/_apis/build/Definitions/160?revision=15",
  "variableGroups": null,
  "variables": {
    "system.debug": {
      "additionalProperties": {},
      "allowOverride": true,
      "isSecret": null,
      "value": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your build definition? Are you able to run your build locally?

Comment: Didn't know another way to share the build definition other than JSON ... but it's up there now. This is an Ionic 1 project so no, I haven't tried building it locally, we use VS and the TACO tools stuff to help us not have to manage all that, it's also why I'm using the VS 2017 hosted machines. But, it's a good point, i'll start going down that path locally now.

Comment: You could capture a screenshot of your build definition. And please let us know the result of your local build.

Comment: So building locally did fail, but it fails further down the pipe than this job. I get past gradle starting and it does it's downloads and stuff. locally this is the error it throws eventually but i feel like it's unrelated, i dunno, maybe not: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Comment: I can get my local build to work with a plugin workaround ... so yeah, these two issues aren't related. when i do cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release  --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=27.+ it fixes the 'appComponentFactory' issue and gives me an apk but the hosted VS 2017 build still stalls

Comment: What is environment/software required to run your project? Could you check [Hosted VS2017 image](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md) to see whether it meets your requirement?

Comment: It's just an ionic 1 / cordova project, for android we are targeting api 27, locally i can get it to build using cordova 6.5.0, 7.1.1 and 8.0.0 ,the hosted VS2017 image should be fine, i have a taco.json file to specify cordova versions but they all do the same thing. Also, thanks for looking into this with me, i do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our ionic 1 project had a bunch of weird hook scripts in the hooks directory that i think at this point have been implemented in the cordova build process. Cleaning our hooks directory up to only what was necessary fixed this.